# NodeJS : exported class has a method returning undefined

Tags: node.js, module, undefined

I exported a class to represent a point in a grid. This class has a "distance" methods.

When I use this method in another nodeJs file, the result is always Undefined. 
I can't understand why.

Here is my source code :

```
const math = require('Math')

function checkCoordinate(x) {
 if ( (typeof x == 'number') &&
   (x > 0) && (x % 1 == 0 ) ) {
     return x
   }
 else throw (new Error('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'))
}
/**
  * Build a new square for a grid
  * @class
  * @classdesc Represent a square in a grid
  */
class square {
  constructor (abscissa, ordinate) {
    try {
      this.abscissa = checkCoordinate(abscissa)
      this.ordinate = checkCoordinate(ordinate)
    } catch (err) {
      throw (err)}
  }

  distance (square2) {
    if (square2 instanceof square)
      return
      math.ceil (
        math.sqrt(
          math.pow((this.abscissa-square2.abscissa), 2) +
          math.pow((this.ordinate-square2.ordinate), 2)
        )
      )
    throw (new Error('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'))
  }
}

module.exports = square
```

When I try to use it :

```
var Square =  require ('./objects/square.js')

var sA = new Square(1,1)
console.log(sA.distance(new Square(20,20)))
```

The result is undefined :

```
$ npm start

> target-rpg@1.0.0 start D:\Documents\Programmation\NodeJS\target-rpg
> node server.js

undefined
```

I should get 27. Instead of it I got Undefined. 
I can't figure it out.

I'm using node 8.1.4

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the result without computing it by mentioning `return` and `math.ceil` on different line. Both should be on same line.

```
return math.ceil(
    // sqrt code
)
```

Comment: Oh. It proves that my stupidity has no limit. 
Thank you Mukesh